# Why is my cloth not subdivided correctly in the rendered image?

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

[image: Cloth Render Trubs]
Just trying to render some physics cloth / rubber. All modifiers are set to visible, with Sudivision as the first modifier in the stack, followed by Solidify and finally Cloth.

Have baked up to and past the frame I want to render. However, I'm getting the result to the right - can anybody give me a clue as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: One clue might be to increase subdivision on your cloth, otherwise the cloth physics has not much to work with...

Comment: Please explain how you setup the subdiv modifier (or add a screen shot of your modifier stack). Issue could be as simple as making the render settings match the viewport settings.

Comment: Please show an image of the subsurf modifier. that shows Preview and render settings/

Comment: It is also a solution. ajajajaja

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, while I had increased the Subdivision in the Modifier Stack to 6 for Viewport, I had failed to change it from 2 for Render. (In the following image I have changed the Render Subdivisions from 2 to 6)

[image: Fixy!]
[image]
Thank you to the commentators, error lay between keyboard and chair.

Comment: Noted, good point, fixed.